# What information does a server know about the client that does the request?

Tags: http, request

When a web server receives a http(s) GET request from a client, it has access to some information such as:

- The client IP
- The request itself :

  - the headers (including the cookies)
  - the content
- and... that's all ?

I am wondering if there is something else.

Indeed, I am trying to make a server that can access to a page where it can collect some information to update its database. The site denied access to my server but not to web browsers, even if I replicate the IP, the headers and the content.

Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, it's only what is contained in the request itself. The server cannot reach back to the client to "pull" information, it only has the information contained in the HTTP request and the underlying TCP/IP packet. That's:

- the requesting IP address
- the HTTP headers, including requested URL and HTTP method
- the HTTP request body, if any
- if it's HTTPS, any data exchanged during the TLS handshake, which is usually not very relevant for identifying anything significant

All of that information is *voluntarily provided* by the requesting client.

Comment: Ok thanks. So I've no idea why the server that host the page can make the difference between a request from a web browser and a request from my server.

Comment: Probably the user agent, or cookies. Or blacklisted range of IPs.

Comment: I've set the user agent to `Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64; rv:60.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/60.0` and I can access to the site with Mozzila without cookies. About the IP, the server is in localhost, so it's the same.